# Authenticate GameKit local player using swift

Tags: authentication, block, gamekit, swift

Im looking to migrate a game over to swift, the only trouble I am having is with blocks/closures. It's the syntax I just don't understand, whereas in Objective C I would use:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

etc.etc. but I'm not sure how to go about doing the same in Swift. I know it's simple but I just can't get it to work, even after reading the Swift book and googling answers myself. I'm only a hobbyist programmer so I'm far from perfect at all this.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you would do it in Swift:

```
var localPlayer = CGLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
    //handle authentication
}
```

The documentation for closures can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_117).

Comment: Thanks for your incredible quick answer, I'll try it later. I was playing around with stuff like this but because there was no autocomplete prompt I assumed I had been doing something wrong.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with swift!

Comment: This method has now changed to authenticateHandler as of Xcode 6 beta 6

Comment: The parameters need to be optional now, {(viewController : UIViewController?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

Answer (score 7):

This is how you authenticate in Swift using Xcode 6.1 +:

```
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if ((viewController) != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{

            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
```