# Closure not compiling when setting GKLocalPlayer's authenticateHandler property - Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038314/authenticate-gamekit-local-player-using-swift/24038507#24038507) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277011/how-authenticate-a-local-player-with-swift?rq=1) don't compile.

The code in my SpriteKitSceneViewController,

```
var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {((viewController : UIViewController?, error : NSError?) -> Void)? in
//handle authentication
}
```

produces these errors:
**Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'**
**Expected expression**

The authenticated property is defined as:

```
var authenticateHandler: ((UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void)? { get set }
```

I've read the documentation on closures, but I didn't find anything on optional closures. I thought about using a function instead but I couldn't get that to work either. How can I make this compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write [closure-signature](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/closure-signature) at the top of the [closure-expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/closure-expression). (It's conditionally optional.)

In your code `((viewController : UIViewController?, error : NSError?) -> Void)?` is not a valid *closure-signature*, you need to remove outermost `(...)?`.

And when you write parameter types explicitly, they need to match exactly as the parameter types of the closure type. So, your second parameter's type needs to be `Error?`, not `NSError?`.

With two things above fixed, you can write something like this:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController?, error : Error?) -> Void in
    //handle authentication
}
```

---

But omitting all unneeded parts, you can write it more easily:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {viewController, error in
    //handle authentication
}
```

In most cases, you can omit`->Void`, and in almost all cases, Swift can infer the parameter types. I prefer omitting type annotations when Swift would never fail to infer them.